# How do I create multiple pagination instances for a single model/controller in CakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, pagination

I have a view with two different actions of the same model (An item list sorted by the most recent, and the same list sorted by the most popular). One list I want to paginate with 8 items at a time and one with 12 items at a time. I'm using AJAX to page in the items. How do I go about setting up the controller to handle this task? The problem seems to be that I can't create two different pagination instances, so I can only paginate in the same number of items regardless of the action.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**What I've tried so far**

Basically trying to set limits specific to each action, rather than the initial pagination helper:

`var $paginate = array('order'=>array('Category.name'), 'limit'=>'8');`

That's what the helper looks like, and it feeds in whatever the limit is. Even if I remove that limit and try to apply it like so:

```
var $paginate = array('order'=>array('Item.name'));

function discover_list(){    
    $this->set('d_ajax_items', $this->paginate('Item', array('Item.discover_order' => null, 'Item.moderated' => 1), null, 'Item.id DESC', null, 8));
}

function trend_paging(){
    $this->set('trend_items', $this->paginate('Item', array('Item.moderated' => 1),NULL,  'rank DESC', NULL, 12));  
}
```

The limit on the end of the action is ignored, and it feeds in some default 20 items at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I misunderstood your original question. If you want to set different limits to each action, you can do this

```
function discover_list() {    
    $this->paginate['limit'] = 8;
    $this->paginate['conditions'] = array('Item.discover_order' => null, 'Item.moderated' => 1);
    $this->set('d_ajax_items', $this->paginate('Item'));
}
```

**Edit**

A little nice way

```
$this->paginate = array(
    'limit' => 8,
    'conditions' => array('Item.discover_order' => null, 'Item.moderated' => 1),
);
$this->set('d_ajax_items', $this->paginate('Item'));
```

Comment: This looks good. I'll have to try it a little later, but thank you very much! Just out of curiosity, how could I have made it a little clearer?

Comment: Worked brilliantly, dude. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I've  done  this before and I wished I hadn't. Keeping the two in synch is confusing for the end user and a nightmare for the developer.

What have you tried already? I'm sure you can have two instances, but you'll need to pass the parameters directly into the function `paginate()` rather than setting them on the class variable `paginate`.

*Edit*

To avoid confusion I almost always define the pagination options in the call itself.

In your second example, you pass six parameters to paginate() but it only takes three:

```
function paginate($object = null, $scope = array(), $whitelist = array())
```

If you omit $object and pass an array as the first arg, the last two args move to the left.

Have you tried entering the order and limit values as an array in the third position  ($whitelist)?

http://api13.cakephp.org/class/controller#method-Controllerpaginate

http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/controller/#line-1056

Comment: Understood on your first point. This is a client demand :) Check my updated question for more information.

Comment: It always is. I'll check when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

You can start your page with 2 empty divs and call via ajax 2 different urls mapped to controller/action. Then you only have to worry about ajax pagination, but you won’t have any cakephp issue because each pagination works into his own action.

This is not a really good approach if you want [unbostrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript), but if your entire app require javascript, it will work.

Comment: The problem isn't in the javascript so much as it's in Cake. I need the backend to feed in the right data. The AJAX pagination works beautifully using the method you describe. It's just the datasets that the framework is handing back that is wonky.